# Jasperserver REST api: is it possible to run report with POST?

Tags: rest, jasperserver

We are trying to setup a report application with Jasperserver on back-end. It has been so far so good with GET requests.

Tricky part is: we have **a lot** of params in those reports. At this rate, it *theoretically* can get as bad as

> ttp://192.168.202.234:8080/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/smp_folder/interactive.html?showID=true&showOperator=true&showDispatcher=true&showCalledAt=true&showDeliveredAt=true&showLeftAt=true&showArrivedAt=true&showFinishedAt=true&showBackAt=true&showAddress=true&showCaller=true&showFIO=true&showBirthday=true&showJob=true&showSocStatus=true&showReason=true&showType=true&showRecievePlace=true&showCrewMembers=true&showIsIntoxicated=true&showComplaints=true&showAnamnesis=true&showHealthStatus=true&showEfficiency=true&showAidAcceptance=true&showAidRefuse=true&showTransportationRefuse=true&showAidResult=true&showActiveCall=true&showActiveVisit=true&showDeliveryMethod=true&showCallResult=true&showArriveTime=true&showCallTime=true&showDeliveredTime=true&showWaitTime=true&showDiagnosis=true&diagnosis=d1&showCrewNumber=true&crew=543548e7-2acf-4383-a345-f489613b36ea

It feels seriously wrong to roll with this huge GETs here, so question is: is there any way of doing the same stuff with POST request?

Comment: Having the same exact issue: using `POST` causes JasperServer to reply with a 405 status code (method not allowed).

Without this sort of API, it is impossible to decouple JasperServer from underlying DB-level data-structures or bi-directional coupling (JasperServer uses an external resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the webservices (included with the war file install) guide on v6 you can run a report with a POST

3.2.1 Running a Report Asynchronously

In theory there is no reason you can't specify lots of parameters with GET (up to browser limit) the lowest limit you are likely to hit would be 2000 chars on older versions of IE. Limit on FF/Safari is around 65,000 I believe